# Using For Loop In stead of While loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

```
i = 0
numbers = []

while i < 6:
    print "At the top i is %d" % i
    numbers.append(i)

    i = i + 1
    print "Numbers now: ", numbers
    print "At the bottom i is %d" % i


print "The numbers: "

for num in numbers:
    print num
```

How do I get the exact output using a `for` loop only. I tried a few things, but it simply won't happen. Is it possible at all?

Comment: On a side note, your indentation is wrong in the above example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest *direct translation* of your code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

i = 0
numbers = []

for j in xrange(6):
    print "At the top i is %d" % i
    numbers.append(i)

    i = i + 1
    print "Numbers now: ", numbers
    print "At the bottom i is %d" % i


print "The numbers: "

for num in numbers:
    print num
```

When constructing a `list` in this manner, *list comprehensions* are often a better approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

numbers = [i for i in xrange(6)]

print "The numbers: "

for num in numbers:
    print num
```

In this case, your code could be simplified even further:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "The numbers: "
for num in xrange(6):
    print num
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is having the "exact output," then:

```
numbers = []
for i in range(6):
    print("At the top i is %d" %i)
    numbers.append(i)
    print("Numbers now: ", numbers)
    print("At the bottom i is %d" %(i+1))
print("The numbers: ")
[print(num) for num in numbers]
```

Python3.

Comment: I am using Python 2. How much of the above code is different?

Comment: I know there are no parentheses around print in Python 2, and I'm not sure about generator expressions. If anything, you can use what you initially had instead of [print(num) for num in numbers]